# Database -- commit a transaction timing issue

Tags: database

I am really confused about how commit a transaction will take some time to make updates.

Here is the scenario I am trying:
1. Commit a transaction(all update statement)
2. go to a database and try to get updates

Here, when I try to get updates then sometime  I don't get the latest update.
Sometime i get old version of a data.

here is some more details:
In Transaction I have two update statements say it updates one int field by 1 on each updates
For Example : I have value 5 in db before any updates now transaction with two updates will make it 7.

after committing a transaction, I try to fetch it using connection object and PreparedStatement.

The result I am getting is 6. not 7. Although When I can see 7 on DB.

So, I did some more debugging and try to track time stamp for updates on db and time stamps for fetching data.

Under my surprise my time stamp for fetching a data is less than time stamp for last update on DB.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Can you explain some more about the specifics of what you're doing?  There is no structural problem with a `commit` call followed by a separate process/task/whatever going to the DB and asking for that data.  If you're not seeing some of the data, it would suggest that you haven't committed all of it *or* the transaction on the reader process may need to be "freshened" (for lack of a better term).

Comment: you need to commit between each update - most RDBMS will proved a read consistent view - which means you will get the results 'at the time you begin the query', even if some data is changing as you read the results.

Answer (score 0):

Much like what the others say, your code may only be reading the committed transactions. Perhaps you think that you committed the transaction when in reality you did not. For instance your query on the db might be an uncommitted read (select * from table where x=some_value with ur) and your code is doing a committed read, which would be why you are seeing different values.